# What does "Service error: Spreadsheets" mean?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a code that works... sometimes... randomly, it stops while running and gives me this error. I am happy to provide code, but I just thought there might be a clear definition of what this error message means. Edit- I have, in fact, added the script below.

```
function onOpen() {
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0098230948YUIAEr80w9er");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
sheet.clearContents();


sheet.appendRow(["pp","v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9", "v10", "v11", "v12"]);
sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
 var files = folder.getFiles();
 while (files.hasNext()) {
 var file = files.next();


   var otherSheet= SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Project Overview");

   var data = otherSheet.getRange("B3:I30").getValues();


 var v1 = data[1][0];
 var v2 = data[2][0];
 var v3 = data[0][0];
 var v4 = data[4][0];
 var v5 = data[5][0];
 var v6 = data[8][0];
 var v7 = data[3][0];
 var v8 = data[14][0];
 var v9 = data[1][7];
 var v10 = data[2][7];
 var v11 = data[3][7];
 var v12 = data[0][7];



var url = file.getUrl(); 
var name = "Site Detail"; 
var semi = ";";  
var hyp = "=hyperlink(\"";
var quot = "\"";
var clos = ")";
var pp = hyp  + url + quot + semi + quot + name + quot + clos;


 if (Status != 'Those' && Status != 'This' && Status != 'That' && Status != 'Other')


{ sheet.appendRow([pp,v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9,v10,v11,v12])

 sheet.sort(2);}
```

}}

Comment: There's another SO discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165101/service-error-spreadsheets-on-google-scripts) discussing possible causes. Doesn't look like there is one single reason. Some code would help, too. Might be able to pinpoint what's happening.

Comment: That you for pointing me to that post.   I do not see anything applicable. I have posted my script that is failing (again, only sometimes). If you see anything that may be causing it, I would greatly appreciate knowing.  Thanks!

Comment: There was another thread that linked the `appendRow` method to failing scripts when there were no more empty rows at the bottom of the sheet. Try adding some blank rows if there aren't any and see if that stops the failures.

Comment: I saw that and appreciate, but there are already 1000 rows and that data only comes in at 161 rows when finishing... Do you think that there is something just in adding an extra row that helps, even if there are plenty?

Comment: So I have run the debugger five or six times and while I get the  "Service Error: Spreadsheets" error it DOES select a particular row that is the issue... sometimes it selects                                                                     var data = otherSheet.getRange("B3:I30").getValues();                                 And Other times it selects                                                                        { sheet.appendRow([pp,v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9,v10,v11,v12])

Comment: But ONLY those two lines and even then, only occasionally

Comment: ok, so I will try one more comment, then just start a new question, unless it is a quick reply.  I have determined that there are many little errors that are occasionally being thrown here... I will add to the list the AHSLIDdfuoiwe8097969sldifhsod" document does not exist.  Could it have been deleted?"  It is like for moment, the script cant find it.  So, it all brings me to this:  is there a way here to use try() and catch() not to rerun the WHOLE script if there is an error, but to just rerun one iteration within the while (files.hasNext()) {?

Comment: It seems like the service error can be caused by calls to various sheets, and if they don't happen before the next function is called, then you receive the error. Not sure a whole lot can be done other than simplifying external calls...I know that's not very helpful...

Comment: Thanks Brian.  Do you know if there is a way to pause between functions in my code above?  I know how to add pauses between functions in general, but in the context of the while (files.hasNext()) {, is there a way to pause between each?

Comment: I don't know if it's best practice (definitely hacking away on my projects...) but I put breakpoints between each function. In other words, Function 1 calls function 2 when it's done. Because you're in a loop at that point, it probably isn't an option. Not sure of other methods.

Comment: Ill post an answer, but simply adding a 200 millisecond sleep fixed this!

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165101/service-error-spreadsheets-on-google-scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, changing the script to this worked:

```
 var files = folder.getFiles();
 while (files.hasNext()) {
 var file = files.next();
 Utilities.sleep(200);
```

I cannot tell you why, other than that I suspect it allows the script to "catch up" with itself before moving to the next file.  I hope this is helpful to someone, and would love if someone could explain to all of us WHY this worked.